# Apple Mach-O Linker Error - Undefined Symbols for architecture arm64

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, unity-game-engine

I have an issue while Running my unity project on xcode. I get over 78 Apple Mach-O Linker Errors. I have implemented a bunch of Plugins as well. However I have included all the frameworks that are required for those plugins to run.Now I am not sure why I keep getting these issues. I have attached an image of some of the Mach-o linking errors im getting. Im trying to deploy the build for iPhone 6 running 8.2 and it Xcode 6.2.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/eZoY8.png

Thanks

Comment: It seems that you added a library which is not build with correct architecture, arm64. The warning at the beginning points this...

Comment: And also, which architecture selected in PlayerSettings for iOS? Is it, arm64 or anything else? http://screencast.com/t/ZGL6I3cSCgD